# Disable button in Nativescript Raddataform

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I'm using commitMode="Immediate" and I'm trying to disable my save button when any input is invalid. 
What is the recommended approach to achieve this?

I understand that I can just set a variable when using "manual" mode from my component, but I can't find any event that represents a change in validity of preferably the complete Raddataform (otherwise of a single property) when using Immediate validation.

Comment: You may listen to `propertyValidated` event and check if the entire form has any errors (may be using `.hasValidationErrors()`) and disable the button if there is any.

Comment: That means that I need to add that event on all properties separately, right?

Comment: No, that means you can use the event on RadDataForm that's triggered whenever a property is validated. It's a common event for all properties in form.

Comment: Ok that's a decent solution then, thanks!

Comment: Hum... `.hasValidationErrors()` seems to be triggering `propertyValidated`, causing a stackoverfow. Any idea why or how to get around it?

Comment: Figured it out. adding a setTimeout in the event handler works!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by listening for validation events and then updating your model.

From [this example](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-ui-samples-vue/blob/bb5445b054215771e3e81496929a7a11e72e2ac9/dataform/app/examples/ValidationEvents.ts), add the `propertyValidated` listener:

```
<RadDataForm @propertyValidated="onPropertyValidated"  ...></RadDataForm>
```

Then change your state:

```
methods: {
  onPropertyValidated({ object, propertyName, entityProperty }) {
    this.$refs.button.enabled = !entityProperty.isValid;
  }
}
```

You will probably want to keep track of all validations in this case, or you could use the complete `dataform.hasValidationErrors()`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the NS-Vue solution, but totally applicable in Angular.

Add a `@propertyValidated="onValidateForm"` event listener that triggers on each validation. Then you can use `hasValidationErrors()` on the form to see if the form is valid. The only trick is that is has to be wrapped in a `setTimeout()`, like so:

```
onValidateForm(event) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.validated = !event.object.hasValidationErrors();
        console.log("form valid: " + this.validated);
    }, 100);
}
```

For a complete solution, see [this playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=P4HCCn&v=15).