# How to disable button when RadDataForm is not validated?

Tags: nativescript-vue, nativescript-telerik-ui, nativescript-plugin

## disable the button when form is not validated.

[{N} Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=P4HCCn&v=12)

[A similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59729520/disable-button-in-nativescript-raddataform) was asked before. It says it's solved but what exactly was the decent solution? Did I miss something?

[Form validation documentation page](https://docs.nativescript.org/vuejs/ns-ui/DataForm/dataform-validation) is broken it has markdown errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `@propertyValidated="onValidateForm"` event listener that triggers on each validation. 
Then you can use `hasValidationErrors()` on the form to see if the form is valid. The only trick is that is has to be wrapped in a `setTimeout()`, like so:

```js
onValidateForm(event) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.validated = !event.object.hasValidationErrors();
        console.log("form valid: " + this.validated);
    }, 100);
}
```

For a complete solution, see [this {N} Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=P4HCCn&v=22).

Comment: Even if it is using that crappy `setTimeout`, I think this solution is better than @ian-macdonald's because it will work no matter how many fields you have.

Answer (score 1):

I answered the other question.

I have also updated [your playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=P4HCCn&v=16).

Comment: Multiple input version of this solution is [in this {N} Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=P4HCCn&v=19)  As you recommended in slack, I will Leave the button enabled, but then do something different if hasValidationErrors(). Thank you